# Why is the property of a component valued inside the body of a subscribe while it is not defined outside?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve data from a sql server table using http.get used inside the constructor of an angular component 5. The data I can assign to a component property inside the subscribe, but when I look for it to use the property value I get a "undefined" value. Below is the code and the output obtained:

### topic.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class TopicService {
  topics: Topic[];
  name: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string,
    private router: Router,
    public auth: AuthService) {    

    http.get<Topic[]>(baseUrl + 'api/Topic/List').subscribe(result => {
      this.topics = result;
      console.log(this.topics);         // It is valued
    }, error => console.error(error));

console.log(this.topics);     // It is no longer valued - it is undefined

  }

}
```

As from "Chrome DevTools":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbQFj.png)

I don't understand, I have the data and I can't use it. Even the most obvious indications are welcome.

Comment: You're seeing this because the second `console.log` in the code is actually running before the first `console.log` in the code. This happens due the fact that http calls are asynchronous. `this.topics` will be undefined until the http call completes, and the value gets assigned inside the `subscribe`.

Comment: So how can I intercept the data and store it in the property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is *no longer valued* - it is undefined

If you look at your image, it's actually *not yet defined/"valued"*. You can see this is the case because `undefined` is logged to the console *before* the array.

`get` is asynchronous so the callback in `subscribe` hasn't yet run, hence the behavior.